# Recognize special key char without kycode

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you hit backspace for instance the console shows an empty string for `keyVal`, but that is misleading because `keyVal.length` is equal to **1** and there's a hidden char

```
element.on('keydown',function(e){
   var keyVal = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
});
```

Is it possible to detect these special keys that doesn't input value? Probably without listing and checking their key codes. Or at least an efficient way of doing it with low risk of omitting any keys.

Comment: You can use [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event in conjunction with [`event.charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.charCode) property. Although now the latter is about to be deprecated, it is still supported by most browsers. It returns the Unicode value of the key pressed if it printable. Note that in Webkit browsers `keypress` doesn't fire if the pressed key isn't printable.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a regex over the `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)`.

```
element.on('keydown',function(e){
   var keyVal = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/g,'');
});
```

That should replace any character not a digit, letter or space

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Generally it show good results, but unfortunately it fails with some chars like `\``,`~` which do input value. And it might have others in utf-8.
http://jsfiddle.net/0b581Lrz/